# Export table in hbase

Tags: hadoop, hbase

After you kick off the export job i.e. :

```
hadoop jar /path/to/hbase-0.20.3.jar export your_table /export/your_table
```

Does it include all versions of the record? or you have to specify that explicitly i.e

```
hadoop jar /path/to/hbase-0.20.3.jar export your_table /export/your_table 3
```

using this syntax as an example :

```
Export <tablename> <outputdir> [<versions> [<starttime> [<endtime>]]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default - only latest versions of the records get exported. 
You can optionally specify max number of versions to be exported and, also time frame.
Look here  
http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/hbase/hbase-0.90.3/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/Export.java.html (line 91) what happens to your versions parameter. It is passed to the Scan, which will be used to read the data.